# Access adding column of type decimal(number with fieldsize decimal)

Tags: sql, ms-access, command, ms-access-2007

In access 2007 how to add a column of type decimal to the access table using query?
In GUI i can select data type as Number and for that i can set field size as Decimal. 
Now i want to do the same using query.How it can be done?
i tried running following in access query option.but didn't work

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyField DECIMAL (10,3)
```

Also How can i ad column with data type Date/time and format as longtime.So please tell me how both of this can be done using query OR by using any code.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine.

The decimal data type isn't supported in the default Jet 4.0 mdb file. You have to use the SQL Server compatibility syntax (ANSI 92) setting to use the decimal data type in the SQL Window.

Click on the menu, Tools > Options. Click on the Tables/Query tab. Mark the check box for "This database" in the SQL Server compatibility syntax (ANSI 92) section. This mode will affect the entire db, including queries with wildcards, so you may want to try this on a copy of your db

Comment: sorry i didn't get Tools > Options in access 2007. Also wgere should it be enabled?

Comment: Please see this link, I think it better explains what needs to be done.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/set-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070486.aspx

Comment: Using ADO i can run the query CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyField DECIMAL (10,3)" and it works fine. But if use ODBC for the same then it gives error like "ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in field definition." Why do this happen?How it can be done in ODBC?

Comment: If you are using a Access database, then you cannot connected to a Access database via ODBC. As noted you can (should) just use the table designer, or CurrentProject as you note.

Answer (score 0):

VBA Solution

```
Dim db As Database
Dim t As TableDef
Dim f As Field
Dim p

Set db = CurrentDb
Set t = db.TableDefs("myTable")
Set f = t.createField("myDateField", dbDate)
Call t.Fields.Append(f)

Set p = f.CreateProperty("Format", dbText, "Long Date")
Call f.Properties.Append(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

The office.microsoft link above has disappeared now too.  Here's how to set the SQL Server Compatibility Syntax flag in Access 2007 (and maybe later - I can't check as I only have 2007):

- Click the round Office button in the top left hand corner
- Access Options
- Object Designers
- Click either of the options under SQL Server Compatible Syntax, depending on whether you want it to apply to just this database, or all future databases

If the "This database" checkbox is disabled, try closing and reopening the database, and go through these steps again without touching any other part of the database first

After this change, using legacy "DECIMAL(11,2)" SQL when creating/altering tables worked fine.

Comment: You most certainly do not want out of the blue to turn on ANSI SQL compatibility in an existing application. Even simple wild card sql such as LastName like 'Smi*' has to be changed to LastName like 'Smi%'. You quite much render an existing application useless if not built from the ground up with that option in mind and turned on. I suppose for a one time table change one could do this, but it likely easier to just use some code or use currentProject.Execute.